# jQuery - show/hide the element inside of another element and clicking outside of that element

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, accordion, slidedown, slideup

HTML:

```
<div class="portlet">
<h3 class="">Blogs</h3>
<div class="portlet-content">
    <div class="teaser">
        <div class="image-with-caption">
            <img src="blogs1_peq.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <p> Some text here </p>
        <ul class="link-list">
            <li xmlns:fofx="urn:FunctionObjectForXsl" class="newwindow"><a href="http://theenergycollective.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;">The Energy Collective</a></li>
            <li xmlns:fofx="urn:FunctionObjectForXsl" class="newwindow"><a href="http://sustainablecitiescollective.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;">Sustainable Cities Collective</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to create a sort of accordion. The idea is to display only the headeline and the image inside the div with the class image-with-caption. I made this code in jQuery to wrap everything bellow the div of the image and hide it:

```
 var $createDiv = $('.image-with-caption').nextAll();
 for(var i=0, len = $createDiv.length; i < len; i+=2){
     $createDiv.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="master" />');
 }
```

And I get something like this:

```
...
<div class="image-with-caption">
    <img src="blogs1_peq.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="master">
    <p> Some text here </p>
    <ul class="link-list">
        <li xmlns:fofx="urn:FunctionObjectForXsl" class="newwindow"><a href="http://theenergycollective.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;">The Energy Collective</a></li>
        <li xmlns:fofx="urn:FunctionObjectForXsl" class="newwindow"><a href="http://sustainablecitiescollective.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;">Sustainable Cities Collective</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
...
```

When I click on the headline it should show me the new div created and hidden by jQuery, but I can't figure out how can I do this.

jQuery Code:

```
var $createDiv = $('.image-with-caption').nextAll();
for(var i=0, len = $createDiv.length; i < len; i+=2){
    $createDiv.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="master" />');
}
$('.master').hide(); //Hide/close all containers


//On Click
$('.portlet h3').click(function(){
    if( $(this).nextAll().is(':hidden') ) { 
        $(this).removeClass('active').next().siblings().next().slideUp();
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().siblings().next().slideDown(); 
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active').siblings().next().siblings().slideUp();
    }
    return false;
});
```

The problem is, I sincerely don't know how to tell jQuery to display the div with the class master bellow the h3 I just clicked. Unfortunately I can't change the HTML code, since this code is generated by a CMS, and I have several div.portlet in the same page, so the code will affect all of them, and that's what I want.

:(

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this `$(this).parent('.portlet').find('.master').show();` to the click event for the `h3`